# Where am I to run `yarn start` for substrate front end template?

Tags: substrate

I went on an ubuntu terminal and ran `substrate-front-end-template` then ran `yarn start` but nothing seems to happen. Or where exactly am I to run `yarn start`. When I run `yarn start` on ubuntu, I'm met with this error message `/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/yarn: 12: node: not found`. My chain is already producing blocks.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it sounds like you do not have Node.js installed. Here are some docs I found from nodejs.org for installing: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

From my experience `nvm` is a good, popular package manager for Node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#nvm)